# npm install --save latest and mark in package.json as *

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to npm i --save and save the package installed as "*" (keeping to the latest).
Tried:

```
npm i --save something@latest
npm i --save something@*
```

And I'm out of ideas..

Comment: you shouldn't do that. You never can safely deploy it elsewhere after a certain time

Comment: Hi @user3732793, never say never :). This option exists for a reason. I'm using the * for all my internal packages and I would like my service to get ALL the changes including some breaking changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have `something@*` or `something@latest` in `package.json` then instead of running `npm install` to put it there, you should just put it there yourself and then just run: `npm install` with no other arguments.

Keep in mind that it may install incompatible versions in the future. What npm puts by default is using semver ranges to make sure that you install only compatible versions in the future. If you test your code with e.g. version 1.2.3 then it should still work with 1.2.4 and probably with 1.3.0 but it most likely may not work with 2.0.0 - because in semver the ony reason for a major bump are incompatible changes - see: http://semver.org/

> **Semantic Versioning 2.0.0**
>
> Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, increment the:
>
> 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
> 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
> 3. PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
>
> Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of the risks using '*' and I use the '*' carefully. Just wondered if I'm missing a shortcut of installing directly from the command line.